# Select , Compare and Update using cursors in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, cursor

I have two tables.

`Customer_Master` has 3 Columns `c_id`, `c_addr`, `c_trans`
`Customer_Address` has 3 Columns `c_id`, `c_addr`, `pr`

I fetch `Customer_Master` into Cursor `C1` and `Customer_address` into Cursor `C2`. The Select Statement in Cursor `C2` has a `Where` conditions which is fed from Columns `c_id` and `c_addr` fetched from Cursor C1.

Cursor `C1` Select Statement:
`Select c_trans, c_id, c_addr, from customer_master`

`c_trans` is Primary Key. Not Null and Unique

Cursor `C2` Select Statment:

`Select pr from customer_address where c_id = cid and c_addr = cad`

`pr` Contains only the Values True or False.

Now, I have to check to check weather `pr` contains the value 'True'. If true, nothing has to be done.

If false, It has to update `c_addr` of `customer_master` with the value of `customer_address . c_addr` which has `pr` as True)

```
`Update customer_master 
Set c_addr = (select c_addr from customer_address where pr = 'TRUE' and c_id = cid)
where c_trans = ctrans`
```

How to implement this.

EDITED:

My Code;

```
`declare
cid number;
cadd number;
ctras number;
cr varchar(2);
cad number;
cursor c1 IS
select c_tras, c_id, c_add from customer_master;
cursor c2 IS
select c_address, cr from customer_address where c_id = cid;
begin
open c1;
open c2;
LOOP
fetch c1 into ctras, cid, cadd;
fetch c2 into cad, cr;
if cr='N'
THEN
update customer_master set c_address = (select c_address from customer_address where cr = 'Y' and c_id = cid) where c_tras = ctras;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;`
```

Comment: Not entirely sure I'm following, but this sounds like something you should be doing with a single merge or correlated update statement, not cursors?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @BobJarvis Done!! Sorry :)

Comment: You might try correcting the typos (e.g. `c_tras` instead of `c_trans` in cursor `c1`, fetching 'cr` instead of `pr` in cursor `c2`, checking for `N` instead of `True` in the `IF` statement), you might try closing the cursors before exiting, and  you might add an explanation of what's wrong with the code you've written (i.e. what errors are being produced, or what the expected results are vs. what results are being obtained). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfect.

```
declare
cid number;
cadd number;
ctras number;
pr varchar(2);
vad number;
cursor c1 IS
select ac_tras, cust_id, cust_addr from customer_master;
cursor c2 IS
select pr_adr from customer_address where cust_id = cid and cust_addr = cadd;
BEGIN
open c1;
LOOP
fetch c1 into ctras, cid, cadd;
EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
OPEN c2;
LOOP
fetch c2 into pr;
if pr='Y'
THEN EXIT ;
ELSE
UPDATE customer_master 
set cust_addr = (select cust_addr from customer_address where pr_adr = 'Y' and cust_id = cid) where ac_tras = ctras;
END IF;
EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
END LOOP;
Close C2;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
END;
```